# How to get text of elements in a custom listview?

Tags: android-activity, robotium

I have an adroid app where one actrivity cotains Custom listview in which each item or element is implemented as a separate linearlayout textview. I want to get the text of each element.

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a guess here as your information is lacking a little detail. What you are going to need to do is loop through each element in the listview and then find the text view within the linear layout.

If you look over at the answer I have given over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627894/click-all-the-list-view-elements-while-scrolling-using-robotium/14641941#14641941)

you will want a method like:

```
ListView list = solo.getCurrentListViews().get(0);
for(int i=0; i < list.getAdapter().getCount(); i++){
    View view = getViewAtIndex(list, i, getInstrumentation());
    //do something with the view here
}
```

Where the comment is you will want the code that moves you from the top view (linear layout) and gets you to the text view. This will probably involve casting the returned view to a [view group](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) and then using getChildAt(x) where x is the correct index (I cannot tell you that as i do not have you application to tell!)

Hope this helps.