# List item not being clicked in Robotium tests after initial tests

Tags: java, android, automated-tests, robotium

I am a complete newbie to Robotium, and am trying to test an app after going through some tutorials. My app has a list, with a series of items. The tests are given below:

```
    public void testInitialActivity() throws Exception {

        solo.assertCurrentActivity("WRONG INITIAL ACTIVITY", MainActivity.class);
    }

    public void testItemInList() throws Exception {

        solo.clickOnText("opera");
        assertEquals(true, solo.searchText("Info-desk"));
    }

    public void testItemInfo() throws Exception {

        solo.clickOnText("opera");
        solo.clickOnText("Info-desk");
        assertEquals(true, solo.searchText("information"));
    }

    public void testTButton() throws Exception {

        solo.clickOnButton("ITEMS");
        assertEquals(true, solo.searchText("You are not an active user"));

    }
```

The first 2 tests are passing, i.e testInitialActivity and testItemInList. For testItemInfo, however, the list is scrolled down to the very bottom, but no item is clicked, even though "Info-desk" is there. For the 4th test as well, the "ITEMS" is not clicked. Thus those 2 tests are failing. Can someone point out my mistake please? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

To click an item in `ListView` please use

```
solo.clickInList(POSITION_IN_LIST, LIST_NUMBER_IN_PAGE);
```

This means you must know what number the list is in your page – which you may not be able to be sure of easily.

Obviously if you just have one list, then this method works the best.

Read also:

[Iterating through a List and clicking on list items in Robotium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15094105/iterating-through-a-list-and-clicking-on-list-items-in-robotium)

[Click all the list view elements while scrolling using robotium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627894/click-all-the-list-view-elements-while-scrolling-using-robotium)